# Manually set bookmarks jump to wrong location when used with tcolorboxes

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox, xparse

I am extending a class to take Cornell styled notes. For this the class heavily relies on `tcolorboxes`.
I want to add bookmarks to the resulting PDF for some of these `tcolorboxes` but no matter what I try the bookmarks jump to the wrong location.

Here is the class:

```
\ProvidesClass{cornell}
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins,xparse}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % Change geometry of pages

\usepackage{bookmark} % Add bookmarks to the resulting PDF
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, % Colour links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = blue, % Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = blue, % Colour of internal links
    citecolor    = red   % Colour of citations
    bookmarks    = true
}

\date{}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \vspace{-3em}
    \pdfbookmark[0]{\@title}{title}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,lowerbox=invisible]
        \Huge\sffamily \@title
    \end{tcolorbox}
%    \vspace{2em}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{extra}{m}
{
    \pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{extra}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        width=\textwidth,
        colframe=black,
        colupper=black,
        opacitybacktitle=1,
        opacitytext=1,
        segmentation style={black!55,solid,opacity=0,line width=3pt},
        fonttitle=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
        title=#1,
    ]
}
{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{note}{o}
{
    \IfNoValueT{#1} {
        \vspace{-1em}
    }{}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        enlarge left by=.34\textwidth,
        width=.66\textwidth,
        overlay={
            \IfNoValueF{#1} {
                \pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{note}
                \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-.34\textwidth]frame.north west) {\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.325\textwidth]#1\end{tcolorbox}};
            }{}
        }
    ]
}
{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{summary}{}
{
    \vfill
    \pdfbookmark[1]{Summary}{summary}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        floatplacement=!b,
        float,
        colframe=black,
        colupper=black,
        opacitybacktitle=1,
        opacitytext=1,
        segmentation style={black!55,solid,opacity=0,line width=3pt},
        fonttitle=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
        title=Summary,
    ]
}
{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

And here is a sample:

```
\documentclass{cornell}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{A topic we're taking notes on}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{extra}{Introduction}
    This can be used to introduce what is about to come, like
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item{What's the first question this section will answer?}
        \item{What's the second question?}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{extra}

\begin{note}[Some key term]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item{A cool thing}
        \item{Another cool thing}
        \item{Not all things are cool}
    \end{itemize}

    That has another paragraph.
\end{note}


\begin{summary}
    A fabulous summary.
    \\\\
    With multiple paragraphs.
\end{summary}

\begin{extra}{Second introduction}
    This is another introduction to a related yet different section.
\end{extra}

\begin{note}[Another term]
    \lipsum[4]
\end{note}
\begin{note}
    \lipsum[5]
\end{note}
\begin{note}
    \lipsum[6-7]
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the pdf bookmark of "Introduction"  correctly points to the "Introduction"  box, while the bookmark of "Second Introduction"  points to "Introduction"  instead. To overcome this, you could change the definition of the `extra` environment to `\NewDocumentEnvironment{extra}{mm}
{
    \pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{#2}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[....` and use it as follows: `\begin{extra}{Second introduction}{secondintro}`.

Comment: For some background info, you can take a look at the `hyperref` manual: `pdfbookmark[level]{text}{name}`, "As name for the internal anchor name is used (in conjunction with level). Therefore the name must be unique (similar to \label)."

Comment: @leandriis That seems to have fixed the issue for the `extra` environments but the bookmarks for the `note` environments do not work at all. Same for the only `summary` environment used.

Comment: The issue with non-unique names of `\pdfbookmark` is also true for the `note` environments. You could adapt its definition correspondingly.

Comment: @leandriis That's what I did but compared to the `extra` environment it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the [tcolorbox documentation](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=106). There is a `bookmark` option that can be given to a `tcolorbox` as long as the `bookmarks` package is loaded. It will add a `pdfbookmark` automatically.

I had to use the `bookmark*` option to be able to manually set the level of the bookmark.

As an example, here is the definition of the title:

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \vspace{-3em}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        width=\textwidth,
        lowerbox=invisible,
        bookmark*={level=0}{\@title}
    ]
        \Huge\sffamily \@title
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

It seems like the uniqueness of the bookmark label is handled by `tcolorbox` automatically.

Comment: If you are working with `cornell.cls` and reading `tcolorbox` documentation, I suggest to look at section "Library xparse". You'll find commands like `\DeclareTColorBox`equivalent to `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and others. This way you can simplify `cornell.cls` code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did apply some of it. See https://gitlab.com/MLNW/cornell-notes-template for the current code.

Answer (score 1):

**Unique destination names**

Macro `\pdfbookmark` from package `hyperref` also defines an anchor that is used as destination for the bookmark. Destination names must be unique. The last argument of `\pdfbookmark` is to be used to provide unique names. Since the class `cornell` defines several entities (environment `note`, ...) that can be used more than once, a counter helps to ensure uniqueness.

1. Counter declaration:

   ```
   \newcounter{BkmCornell}
   \renewcommand*{\theBkmCornell}{\the\value{BkmCornell}}
   ```

   Macro `\theBkmCornell` is redefined to expand to a plain ASCII number.
   (The default definition of `\theBkmCornell` uses `\arabic` that also works
   most of the time, but it might be redefined in some languages.)
2. The counter is incremented right before `\pdfbookmark`, example for inside environment `note`:

   ```
   \stepcounter{BkmCornell}%
   \pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{note\theBkmCornell}%
   ```

   The percent sign avoids trouble with spaces by line ends.

**Placement of the bookmark**

The best place is the top left corner of the entity.

- For example, the bookmark can be placed in vertical mode right before the box
  with the entity. Disadvantage is that care is needed to prevent a page break
  between the bookmark and the box with the entity. This can be tricky, if the
  entity is an environment that adds page break points at its beginning.

  For example, the bookmark should not be used before an environment that can float away (environments `figure`, `table`, or option `float` of environment `tcolorbox`). In this cases the bookmark must go into the environment, see next item.
- Another way is to include the bookmark inside the entity box, but move it to the
  top left corner. Example for environment `note`:

  ```
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
      % ...,
      enhanced,
      overlay={%
          \stepcounter{BkmCornell}%
          \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (frame.north west)
          {\pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{note\theBkmCornell}};%
      },
  ]
  ```

Comment: I tried your solution but some of the created links do not work at all while other are now closer but still off. I found the solution though and will answer the question for others.